# Deleting files in password protected folder with jquery-file-upload

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have blueimp's great jquery-file-upload installed and it works fine until I put it inside a password protected folder (I moved the entire upload folder, not just redirecting where files are saved). I can still upload, but when I click the delete button nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score -1):

the data-url on the delete button seems to contain the username used to access the password protected directory, but not the password.

I changed line 202 of UploadHandler.php   to be

```
(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].':'.$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'].'@' : '').
```

and this seems to fix the problem, though I've not fully tested this yet.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes